# Spring data jdbc - Specific join, specific mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I've got following two tables:

```
Customer
id
name

Order
id
product_name
customer_id
```

with a 1 to 1 relation

and java entities:

```
@Data
public class Customer{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

@Data
public class Order{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column("id")
    private Customer customer; //i want to somehow map this
    private String productName;
}
```

and a controller

```
@Controller
public class MyController{
    //...
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getmap(Model m){
        System.out.println(repository.findAll()) //prints "nullrows" due to wrong sql statement
        return "mytemplate";
    }
}
```

my current issue is, that spring is executing following sql statement:

```
SELECT Order.id, Order.product_name, Customer.id, Customer.name
FROM Order LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer ON Customer.id = Order.id
```

what i actually want is to join on `Customer.id = Order.customer_id` while leaving the classes as they are i.e. the customer reference needs to stay in order.

i've tried every annotation that i could find so far and have made no progress.

EDIT:

I am not allowed to use jpa/hibernate

Comment: what is the relationship between Order and Customer?

Comment: 1 to 1 currently

Comment: When is the SQL statement executed

Comment: when calling "repository.findAll()" in my controller

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to do the following:

```
@Data
public class Customer{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

@Data
public class Order{
    @Id
    private Long customerId;

    private Long id;

    @Column("id")
    private Customer customer; //i want to somehow map this
    private String productName;
}
```

causing this to automatically join on `Customer.id = Order.customer_id`

This does not look like a good fix however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@OneToOne** and **@JoinColumn** annotations for your One-to-One relationship:

```
@Data
public class Customer{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id") 
    private Order order;
}

@Data
public class Order{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")  
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Comment: thats using hibernate isnt it?

Comment: You can use spring data with the persistence provider of your choice (hibernate is one of the most popular), but OneToOne annotation is not of hibernate it is part of java: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne

Comment: oh yeah. but this is still jpa. i am not allowed to use jpa